# react-hook-form coerce cast string to bigInt how to force

Tags: prisma, react-hook-form, zod

Hi I have an issue with form validation.

I have a select dropdown on my page:

```
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, onInvalid)}
          className={`space-y-8 ${showForm ? "visible" : "hidden"}`}
        >
           <FormField
              control={form.control}
              name="country"
              render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Brand location</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Select
                      onValueChange={field.onChange}
                      defaultValue={field.value}
                    >
                      <SelectTrigger
                        className="w-[180px] rounded-md p-2"
                        {...field}
                      >
                        <SelectValue placeholder="Select the country" />
                      </SelectTrigger>
                      <SelectContent className="max-h-[200px] overflow-y-auto ">
                        <SelectItem value="249">Algeria</SelectItem>
                        <SelectItem value="20">Argentina</SelectItem>
                        <SelectItem value="23">Australia</SelectItem>
                      </SelectContent>
                    </Select>
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              )}
            />
            <Button type="submit" isLoading={isPending}>
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Form>
```

I would like to validate the value="20" for example against

```
const myValidator: z.ZodObject({
    name: z.ZodString;
    createdAt: z.ZodDate;
    country: z.ZodBigInt;
)}
```

the issue I am having is that the value property is always interpreted as a string so the onInvalid method is called and the validation errors. I can I force a conversion of that value on the fly?

I tried to do this -> `<SelectItem value={BigInt(20)}>Argentina</SelectItem>` but it still errors out with the only difference being that the select box displays a blank.

The ultimate goal is to add an entry to a database and the field for the country is of type bigInt so I need to get the country mapped to a numerical value.

Comment: Have you tried using the [coercion](https://zod.dev/?id=coercion-for-primitives) method? ```z.coerce.bigint();```

Comment: yeah and that worked. Didn't know about it. If you aren't a native speaker its a bit difficult to understand why they didn't just called it cast like in every other language or framework and opted for coerce - so while I was reading the documentation I didn't stumble over it because of that.

Comment: Haha. I think they chose the term because its more javascripty - [Type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)